# How to get React-Router to only overwrite <main> when changing pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My site has the same header, nav bar and footer across all pages.  I am using react-router and I want to overwrite the html main section with the new pages content everytime a link is clicked.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class BasicExample extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            [
                <Header />,
                <Nav />,
                <Main />,
                <Footer />
            ]
        )
  }
}

function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
            This is a header
        </header>
    )
}

function Main() {
    return (
        <main id='main'>
            Content goes here
        </main>
    )
}

function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer>
            This is a footer
        </footer>
    )
}

function Nav() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                  <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                  <li><Link to="/test">Test</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </Router>
    )
}

function Routes() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                <Route path="/test" component={Test}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

function Home() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Home</h2>
      </div>
    )
}

function About() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
      </div>
    )
}

function Test() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Test</h2>
      </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <BasicExample />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Routes />,
    document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Is this doable with react-router or does it violate some basic reactjs principle?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there a problem with your code that you'd like help with?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  The above code does not work.  When I click on the links, the new page content doesn't overwrite the current "main" section.

Comment: do you have any html file that includes those id ?

Comment: Yes my index.html has the <div id="root"></div> in it. It works except for clicking on the links.  I will check the answers below and respond in it a bit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers.  Here's a solution I came up with that works:

Given an index.html like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="root">
      <header id="header"></header>
      <nav id="nav"></nav>
      <main id="main"></main>
      <footer id="footer"></footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

you cannot write to a parent and a child using ReactDom.render like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('header')
);
```

but you can write to siblings like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('header')
);
ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('main')
);
```

so here's my solution in index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class BasicExample extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="dummy">
                <Header />
                <Nav />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function Header() {
    const element =  <header>This is a header</header>;

    ReactDOM.render(
        element,
        document.getElementById('header')
    );
    return null;
}

function Nav() {
    const element = 
        <Router>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/test">Test</Link></li>
                </ul>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                <Route path="/test" component={Test}/>
            </nav>
        </Router>
    ;

    ReactDOM.render(
        element,
        document.getElementById('nav')
    );
    return null;
}

function Footer() {
    const element = <footer>This is a footer</footer>

    ReactDOM.render(
        element,
        document.getElementById('footer')
    );
    return null;
}

function Home() {
    const element = <h1>Home</h1>

    ReactDOM.render(
        element,
        document.getElementById('main')
    );
    return null;
}

function About() {
    const element = <h1>About</h1>

    ReactDOM.render(
        element,
        document.getElementById('main')
    );
    return null;
}

function Test() {
    const element = <h1>Test</h1>

    ReactDOM.render(
        element,
        document.getElementById('main')
    );
    return null;
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <BasicExample />,
    document.getElementById('header')
);
```

if you want your components to be classes, you can do something like this:

```
class Footer extends React.Component {
    render() {             
        return (
            <Myfoot />
        )
    }
};

function Myfoot() {
    const element =  (
         <div id="home" className="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Footer</h2>
         </div>
     )

     return (
         ReactDOM.render(
             element,
             document.getElementById('footer')
         )
     );

}
```

I tested this all out and it seems to work without warnings or errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Some mixing point

1) You need an html output that contains your id

2) Duplicate Router calls

3) You need To call your route under the switch statement

Somwhere in your html :

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

jsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

class BasicExample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return [<Header />, <Nav />,<Main />, <Footer />];
  } 
}

function Header() {
  return <header>This is a header</header>;
}

function Main() {
  return <main id="main">Content goes here</main>;
}

function Footer() {
  return <footer>This is a footer</footer>;
}

function Nav() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter >
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/test">Test</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </BrowserRouter >
  );
}

function Routes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter >
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter >
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Test</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<BasicExample />, document.getElementById("container"));

ReactDOM.render(<Routes />, document.getElementById("main"));
```

Comment: Thanks Fabien, but this does not address the key question which is how do you direct the output of the Router to the "main" section.  I want my html to look like my example with a "main" section and the router sends its output to this section only.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do and it is similar to what I have in my example, but it does not work. When you click on the links, the content does not change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any rules of react-router is being violated. Exactly same thing is done in the react-router documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but there are a few obvious problems below which I've changed:

1. Move the Router to the main function. (not needed in the navbar)
2. Remove the duplicate ReactDOM.render calls
3. Render main as a switch statement.
4. Remove the Routes function.

   ```
   class BasicExample extends React.Component {
       render() {
           return (
               <Router>
                   <Header />
                   <Nav />
                   <Main />
                   <Footer />
               </Router>
           )
     }
   }

   function Header() {
       return (
           <header>
               This is a header
           </header>
       )
   }

   function Main() {
       return (
           <main id='main'>
                 <Switch>
                   <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                   <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                   <Route path="/test" component={Test}/>
                 </Switch>
           </main>
       )
   }

   function Footer() {
       return (
           <footer>
               This is a footer
           </footer>
       )
   }

   function Nav() {
       return (
               <nav>
                   <ul>
                     <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                     <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                     <li><Link to="/test">Test</Link></li>
                   </ul>
               </nav>
       )
   }

   function Home() {
       return (
         <div>
           <h2>Home</h2>
         </div>
       )
   }

   function About() {
       return (
         <div>
           <h2>About</h2>
         </div>
       )
   }

   function Test() {
       return (
         <div>
           <h2>Test</h2>
         </div>
       )
   }

   ReactDOM.render(
       <BasicExample />,
       document.getElementById('container')
   );
   ```

Comment: Thanks Brub, but this first gave an error "You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>".  I then wrapped the "nav" component in a router and it did display the page, but the links did not work when clicked.  It appears the link to and the Route path commands have to be children of the same Router tag and the content can only appear within that tag so you cannot redirect the output to a different section of the page.  I guess what I want to do cannot be done.

Comment: It can definitely be done.  There can only be one Router in the application and yes it's usually at the root App level, that was a mistake.  But you can have multiple Switch statements in the application, for example each section you want to toggle different components based on the route would be a Switch.